# jpa subgraph and MappedSuperclass throws Unknown entity

Tags: java, jpa, wildfly

I have a silly problem with subgraphs. It's my firsttime with EntityGraphs.

I have following classes im my common lib:

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class NamedDomainObjectWithFiles extends NamedDomainObject {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<File> files;

public Set<File> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

public void setFiles(Set<File> files) {
    this.files = files;
}

}
```

and

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedAttributeNode;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraph;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraphs;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = File.findAll, query = "SELECT f FROM File f ORDER BY f.createdOn"),
@NamedQuery(name = File.findByName, query = "SELECT f FROM File f WHERE f.name = :name") })

@NamedEntityGraphs({ 
@NamedEntityGraph(name = File.EG_LoadRoles, attributeNodes = {   @NamedAttributeNode("roles") }),
@NamedEntityGraph(name = File.EG_LoadALL, includeAllAttributes=true)
})
@Entity
public class File extends NamedDomainObject{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3696244073145217983L;

public static final String findByName = "File.findByName";
public static final String findAll = "File.findAll";
public static final String EG_LoadRoles = "File.EG_LoadRoles";
public static final String EG_LoadALL = "File.EG_LoadALL";

@ManyToMany
private Set<Role> roles;

@ManyToMany
private Set<FileCategory> fileCategories;

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public Set<FileCategory> getFileCategories() {
    return fileCategories;
}

public void setFileCategories(Set<FileCategory> fileCategories) {
    this.fileCategories = fileCategories;
}

}
```

and the class Kunde in my war

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedAttributeNode;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraph;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraphs;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.NamedSubgraph;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import de.xxx.common.domain.Address;
import de.xxx.common.domain.NamedDomainObjectWithFiles;

@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = Kunde.findAll, query = "SELECT b FROM      Kunde b where b.activ=1 ORDER BY b.name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Kunde.findByName, query = "SELECT b FROM Kunde b WHERE b.name = :name") })
@NamedEntityGraphs({ 
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Kunde.EG_loadAll,  
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "files", subgraph = Kunde.SG_filesLoadAll)
        }, 
        subgraphs = {
                @NamedSubgraph(name = Kunde.SG_filesLoadAll, 
                        attributeNodes = { 
                                @NamedAttributeNode("roles"),
                                @NamedAttributeNode("fileCategories") 
                        }
                ) 
        }
) 
})

@Entity
public class Kunde extends NamedDomainObjectWithFiles {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7339308550470317787L;

public static final String findByName = "Kunde.findByName";
public static final String findAll = "Kunde.findAll";
public static final String EG_loadAll = "Kunde.EG_loadAll";

public static final String SG_filesLoadAll = "Kunde.SG_filesLoadAll";

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "kunde", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Objekt> objekte;

public Kunde() {
}

public List<Objekt> getObjekte() {
    return objekte;
}

public void setObjekte(List<Objekt> objekte) {
    this.objekte = objekte;
}

}
```

Everything works fine until i try to activate the subgraph 'Kunde.SG_filesLoadAll' in my class Kunde. During startup i get following exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:   de.xxx.common.domain.NamedDomainObjectWithFiles
```

If i only set

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Kunde.EG_loadAll,  
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "files")
        }
```

no exception is thrown during startup.

I hope you can help me.

I tested this code with the same result on wildfly 8.1 and 9.0.1.

Michael

@Edit:

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ObjektmanagementDS</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>lib/common-0.0.1.jar</jar-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/objektmanagement?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Can you please show your persistence.xml and say where it appears in your deployment?

Comment: I can persist the object to db without any problems. Now i'm trying to load the object from db with the list of files.
 I would like to use EntityGraphs to prevent lazyloadingexception. 
 From the file objects i schould load the lists of roles and filecategories. 
 So i need subgraphs for eagerloading the lists. 
 If i don't use subgraphs, all files will be loaded, but i have no access to the lists.
 If i define the subgraph as shown and try to publish, the deployment will crash..

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same with my deploy.